# How do I change the duration of the robot going backwards

Tags: python, time, robotics

I am just wondering if someone could help me out. I am controlling a robot via a **Raspberry Pi, using Python** and want to know how I can change the amount of time the robot moves backwards for. It's currently on half a second and I would like it to be three seconds. I have listed the code below that I am using thus far.

```
import time
from gopigo import *  # Has the basic functions for controlling the GoPiGo Robot
import sys  # Used for closing the running program

now = time.time()
future = now + 0.500
while time.time() < future:
    bwd()  # Move backward
stop()  
sys.exit()
```

Comment: `future = now + 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, time here is now ("0") plus 0.500 ("half a second").
To change to 3 secs, you need to do "now" plus "3".

Try this and let us know!

```
import time
from gopigo import *
import sys

now = time.time()
future = now + 3

while time.time() < future:
    bwd()

stop()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. I wasn't sure whether `stop()` should be inside the `while` loop or not. It seems strange to me because if you have to keep repeatedly calling `bwd()` within a loop in order to keep something moving, the purpose of a `stop()` method is lost on me.

Comment: @roganjosh you are right, I've just copied/pasted the OP code. I'll edit now, thanks.

Comment: @RyanJones if that worked, mark the answer as replied, so people will know and also this could help others in need.